# Product form Solution of Jackson Network

Tags: queueing-theory

Consider a Jackson network with nodes $\{i:1\leq i\leq n\}$ which have the arrival rates $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from outside and service rates at each node $\{\mu\}_{i=1}^n$. Define $\rho_i=\frac{\lambda_i}{\mu_i}\forall\ i$ Then we know from queueing theory that the steady-state distribution of the number in the system is given by $$\pi(k_1,k_2,\cdots, k_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n \rho_i^{k_i}(1-\rho_i) $$ which takes the product form meaning that "as if" the distribution in the different queues in the steady-state are independent, but really they are not. My question is, does anybody know, what is the physical significance of this remarkably simple result?

Comment: Unless you specify the parts of your question not dealt with [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_network), this is not a real question (and, once again, much too broad for being a good MSE question).

Comment: The [product form solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product-form_solution) might also give some insight, which references a paper where the product form solution is described as "stations are independent in equilibrium".

Answer (score 0):

It's just independent for a special instant of time. Of course the behaviour of the Queues over a span of time can not be independent!

Comment: The distribution has product form when $t\rightarrow \infty$. How is the concept of time variation coming here?